# React Native Version 0.64 - No podspec found for `FBReactNativeSpec`

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, mobile, native

React Native Version 0.64

> [!] No podspec found for `FBReactNativeSpec` in `../node_modules/react-native/Libraries/FBReactNativeSpec

Comment: I have the same problem, and I tried to use `yarn add react-native@0.63` and other versions to fix this. Using a `0.63` version gives errors like the following error: `CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "ReactCommon/jscallinvoker":`

Comment: If you only want images to work for Apple devices follow these instructions: https://ladwhocodes.com/react-native/images-not-loading-in-react-native-on-ios-14-devices-xcode-12/211/

Comment: i have the same error while upgrading to 0.64.4.
Any solutions we can try ?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the issue by re-installing NVM and downgrading Node to 12.5 and it worked for me after a day of headaches..

This fixed it for me:

1. Reinstall node & nvm like explained here:
   https://jamesauble.medium.com/install-nvm-on-mac-with-brew-adb921fb92cc
2. Install older Node version (12.5 in my case) && use it

   nvm install 12.5
   nvm use 12.5
3. Install pods & build